# apache redirect in .htaccess ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this short .htacccess file.

```
Redirect permanent /home http://www.example.com/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(home|about|gallery|video|crafts|contact|press)$ /$1.html [L]
DirectoryIndex home.html
```

**All** of it works on my local MAMP installation.
The **first line doesn't work** (URL passed unchanged) on my actual apache server (Debian.)

I've tried with the Redirect both above and below the RewriteRule and with the first URL with and without a preceding slash (/home and home).

I have an 'AllowOverride All' in the conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available and as I say the rest of the file is being honoured.

mod_alias is installed (in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/)

I don't see anything in the error log.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your .htacces file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home/?$ http://www.example.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(about|gallery|video|crafts|contact|press)/?$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will work, but do you have any theories as to why the simpler 'Redirect' directive isn't?

Comment: I'm not sure why `Redirect permanent /home http://www.example.com/` didn't work on your setup. I have tried that as well and it worked for me.